# How do I add a relation to my parse.com object using the REST API?

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I have two classes, the standard User and my custom class Story.

Every User can have one or more Story. I can save a new User, I can save a new Story (from my .net application using parse.com REST API), but how do I create a relation between them?

I see this example in the documentation:

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MY APP KEY" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MY REST KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"User":{"__op":"AddRelation","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"Vx4nudeWn"}]}}'
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Story/Ed1nuqPvcm
```

How do I "put" this in using POSTMAN (chrome addon) for instance? What is "-d" in this case, it doesnt seem to be a normal url parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems you have a double question there. The first one, on how to create a parse relation via rest api, you answered with the curl example.

About using postman, you can specify the json content under the raw tab (check the image bellow). Also make sure the content type is set to JSON (application/json), in the blueish dropdown next to the tabs.

[image: json postman rest API]

I've tested and worked fine. Hope it helps.

Cheers.